# Как узнать размер видеофрейма?

Tags: c++

без дополнительных библиотек узнать высоту и ширину кадра в видеопотоке
видео в формате .yuv
читаю с помощью

```
    std::ifstream file("imput.yuv", std::ios::ate | std::ios::binary);
```

Comment: а видео-поток в каком виде хотя бы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Никак. Если это действительно поток yuv, он не содержит информации о размерах - только сырые пиксели в этом самом формате yuv.